# Catch Snorlax on the bridge

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Pokemon Let’s Go, is it possible to catch the Snorlax on the bridge prior to beating the Elite 4? I keep trying to catch him but he keeps running away.

Comment: Are you asking about Pokemon Let's Go?

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Wait, I just read up on this. What is the way to catch pokemon in Let's Go? Do you have to get them down to 0 then catch them?

Comment: No I don’t believe so. I checked and did not see any information about this. I have tried berries and ultra balls. I have tried excellent throws. He keeps running. The only thing I can think of is that I have not encountered the elite four yet. I wonder if anyone has caught him prior to beating the elite four.

Answer (score 7):

You can catch that Snorlax much earlier than defeating the Elite 4. I caught it soon after I obtained the Poke Flute. I needed to use berries and ultra balls, and I was able to catch it after several throws.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was going to give up but I will keep trying. Thank you for your answer I appreciate it

Comment: @dscorpiopoke while I haven't played the newest game, I'm assuming that it follows the same catch mechanics as previous games. You could use a Butterfree with Sleep Powder, which should increase the chance of catching it.

Comment: @Zymus Let's Go does not have the same catch mechanics are previous games, so Sleep Powder isn't applicable in this scenario